# Names of modules in PEP8

Tags: python

According to PEP8 (or another reputable convention), am I allowed to name a python module as `MyCoolClass` if it contains a class?

```
class MyCoolClass:
    ...
```

It is supposed to use this module to import this class only, nothing else. If not, what is the best way to name the module?

Please, provide necessary proof links.

Comment: Package and Module Names: "[Modules should have short, all-lowercase names.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)"

Comment: `datetime` module is example for this approach

Comment: I know that, but I'm interested in a possible exception.

Comment: You will probably be confused if you are using module or class at the moment - what else could happen? ;)

Comment: @m.antkowicz Nice note, but I guess there're some advantages to use my  way to name.

Comment: @Formalhaut: If you feel better with your kind of naming then do it. PEP-8 is a suggestion, not an order.. On the other hand it is a very strong suggestion. If you expect to work together with others, you should use the official style guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Python Software Foundation website (about PEP8):

**For Module**

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be
>   used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages
>   should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of
>   underscores is discouraged.

**For Classes**

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

**For your particular case**

If your class is called Foo, you will call your module just "foo" all lowercase. For more on naming conventions and other style advice, see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), the Python style guide.

Comment: If the name is `MyCoolClass`, should I name the module `mycoolclass` or `my_cool_class`?